# How do I get the price of a specified Amazon product?

Tags: php, api, amazon-product-api

I'm listing a specific Amazon product for sale on a site. It's for sale from different Amazon locales, and I would like to list the correct price for these items on my site.

I basically want to input the ASIN/ISBN number and get the price back.

So the input would be 
`$isan = "0123456789"`
And the output would be something like
`Buy from Amazon UK: £15` and
`Buy from Amazon US: $30`

How can I do this? The API documentation is confusing.

Comment: You don't need to add '[PHP]' in your title, that's what tags are for, and they're used extensively.

Comment: You need to include more information about what you have done already and about the Amazon API that you are using. At the moment you are asking us to write your solution for you, rather than posing a specific question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function get_amazon_price() {
       $response = $this->getAmazonPrice("in", "B00SZQ4A70");
       var_dump($response);
    }

    function getAmazonPrice($region, $asin) {

            $xml = $this->aws_signed_request($region, array(
                "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
                "ItemId" => $asin,
                "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
                "ResponseGroup" => "Medium",
            ));

            $item = $xml->Items->Item;
            //var_dump($item);
            $title = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title);
            $url = htmlentities((string) $item->DetailPageURL);
            $image = htmlentities((string) $item->MediumImage->URL);
            $price = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount);
            $discount_price = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->FormattedPrice);
            $code = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->CurrencyCode);
            $qty = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->TotalNew);

            $mrp = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice);



            $response = '';
            if ($qty !== "0") {
                if ($mrp == '') {
                    //echo "MRP = " . $discount_price . '<br/>';
                    //echo "discount_price = 0<br/><hr/>";
                    $response = array(
                        "mrp" => str_replace('INR ', '', str_replace(',', '', $discount_price))
                    );
                } else {
                    // echo "discount_price = " . $discount_price . '<br/>';
                    //echo "MRP = " . $mrp . '<br/><hr/>';
                    $response = array(
                        "discount_price" => str_replace('INR ', '', str_replace(',', '', $discount_price)),
                        "mrp" => str_replace('INR ', '', str_replace(',', '', $mrp))
                    );
                }
            }

            return $response;
            }

        function getPage($url) {

            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $html = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $html;
        }

        function aws_signed_request($region, $params) {

            $public_key = "xxx";
            $private_key = "xxx";

            $method = "GET";
            $host = "ecs.amazonaws." . $region;
            $host = "webservices.amazon." . $region;
            $uri = "/onca/xml";

            $params["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
            $params["AssociateTag"] = ""; // Put your Affiliate Code here
            $params["AWSAccessKeyId"] = $public_key;
            $params["Timestamp"] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
            $params["Version"] = "2011-08-01";

            ksort($params);

            $canonicalized_query = array();
            foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
                $param = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($param));
                $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
                $canonicalized_query[] = $param . "=" . $value;
            }

            $canonicalized_query = implode("&", $canonicalized_query);

            $string_to_sign = $method . "\n" . $host . "\n" . $uri . "\n" . $canonicalized_query;
            $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $private_key, True));
            $signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

            $request = "http://" . $host . $uri . "?" . $canonicalized_query . "&Signature=" . $signature;
            $response = $this->getPage($request);

            //var_dump($response);

            $pxml = @simplexml_load_string($response);
            if ($pxml === False) {
                return False; // no xml
            } else {
                return $pxml;
            }
        }
```